# Google App Emails Recovery for a domain

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps, google-email-settings-api

I have a Domain Name manuelcillero.com i have 200 free Google app emails in this. one of my friend he know all my passwords so wantedly he deleted total account and unsubscribed from Google App. How can i recover this? Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the super admin password (the original account that created the google app). Then follow these directions https://support.google.com/a/answer/1397578?hl=en